# How to use .reduce() on an Array of Objects that has already been reduced?

Tags: json, angular, object, reduce

This Angular app I'm working on is grabbing data from an API in this format:

```
[ {
  "branchNumber" : "025",
  "lineOfBusiness" : "DC-M",
  "taskType" : "Advice",
  "role" : "LU",
  "priority" : "2"
}, {
  "branchNumber" : "null",
  "lineOfBusiness" : "DC-M",
  "taskType" : "Advice",
  "role" : "LU",
  "priority" : "2"
}
etc... ]
```

And I'm using this component to reduce the API data by `taskType`.

```
export class BranchDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    
    public dataList = [];
    public groupedData = [];
    public errorMessage;
    public branchNumber;

    constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit(): void { 
        let stringValue = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('stringValue');
        this.branchNumber = stringValue;
        this._dataService.getData(this.branchNumber).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.dataList = data;
                this.groupedData = this.groupByTask(this.dataList);
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = error);
    }
    groupByTask(data) {
        let grouped = [];
        return grouped = data.reduce((groupedTasks, element) => {
            const taskType = element.taskType;
            if (groupedTasks[taskType] == null) {
                groupedTasks[taskType] = [];
            }
            groupedTasks[taskType].push(element);
            return groupedTasks;
        }, []);
    }
}
```

This works fine and logs out as expected, but now I need to take the `groupedData` array and somehow reduce each `taskType` Object by `branchNumber`, then take each of the reduced `taskType` -> `branchNumber` Objects, and reduce those by `lineOfBusiness`.  Would anyone have any advice on how to achieve this? Every method I've tried so far hasn't worked in the slightest, and I'm running out of ideas, thank you!

The end result should look something like

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this._dataService.getData` returns an `Observable` (if it doesn't just wrap it an `of`) you can do the following and leverage pipes via rxjs.

```
this._dataService.getData.
pipe(
 takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$),
 map(x => groupByTask(x)),
 map(z => groupByBranchNumber(z))
).subscribe(x => ...);
```

Where `this.componentDestroyed$` is defined as a `private componentDestroyed$ = new Subject<void>();` and we make sure to dispose of it in our ngOnDestroy as so:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
        this.componentDestroyed$.next();
        this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
    }
```

I've modified your code somewhat to make it easier for me to reason about, and to also use types to group (as otherwise the grouping key is dynamic and that's an absolute horror show of trying to figure out) so I will link a Stackblitz with my answer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzvqqt?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The end result can be seen in the console. But its structure would be this model:

```
{
  branchNumber: string,
  grouping: { object with the rest of the properties}
}
```

---

**Explanation of what code does:**

- We are leveraging rxjs pipe-able operators, namely `takeUntil`, and `map`.
- Pipe can be thought of as an assembly line, taking the input from one observable and returning the other. If you're familiar with pipes from your CS days you will know that they take one input and result in another input or terminating action.
- `takeUntil`, as the name implies, will keep listening to changes from the observable until the `Subject` for which it is assigned to listen to emits some kind of value. That is handled in the `ngOnDestroy`. We do this to avoid memory leaks, all subscriptions MUST BE DISPOSED OF when no longer needed. Take operators from rxjs will call the `complete` method of the subscribe under the hood.
- the `map` functions will execute the code given and return some sort of new value
- Finally subscribing is what triggers the pipe (as all observables are lazy and will only execute when subscribed) which starts the whole assembly line.

I hope my answer helps/points you in the right direction.